# How to assign the value of the variable in JavaScript function into a Mason variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, form-submit, mason

I am getting `window.location.href` property on click of a button on client side in a javascript variable. My requirement is to send it back to server. How can I get the JavaScript variable value back in Mason code?

One option (which I have implemented currently) is to dynamically create a hidden text field with value set to `window.location.href`, and do a form submit.

How can use ajax here? I am looking for a ajax solution, how it is different from `form.submit()`.

Comment: Answer depends mostly on what the mason code is supposed to *do*.  Is it supposed to replace the current page entirely, for instance?  What role does this "existing URL" play?

Comment: Mason code on server is using this value to pass it on to another function which opens up this location in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the problem is that javascript variable is available to js interpreter in the browser and not to the server side script. You need to somehow get the variable contents and send it back to server. This can be done either via form (which will at least reload the page) or XHR (main technology behind ajax).

I never did XHR directly, but using [dojo framework](http://dojotoolkit.org/) it can look like:

```
dojo.xhrPost( {
    handleAs: "json",
    url:      "http://example.com/whatever",
    content:  { "data_url" : window.location.href }
});
```